# Can 's express plural？

Tags: plural-forms, style, apostrophe

There's a sentence in my textbook:

> My sister got A's in her final exam.

Shouldn't be **As** instead in this case?

Can 's also be a kind of stylish for the plural?

Comment: Yes, it can.  Since "As" is a word, sometimes writers will "set off" the plural "s" with an apostrophe, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a matter of style. In an interesting [2010 blog post](https://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/04/13/faqs-on-style/) that touched on this topic, one writer quoted from the style guide of the *New York Times*:

> Use apostrophes for plurals of abbreviations that have capital letters and periods: M.D.’s, C.P.A.’s. Also use apostrophes for plurals formed from single letters: He received A’s and B’s on his report card. Mind your p’s and q’s.
>
> But do not use apostrophes for plurals of abbreviations without periods, or for plurals formed from figures: TVs, PCs, DVDs; 1990s, 747s, size 7s.

Yet another reason to use an apostrophe in your particular example is to avoid confusing the plural *As* (meaning more than one A) with the adverb/conjunction *as*.

As for the general case (a "stylish" plural), that's probably best avoided most of the time, but rare exceptions exist. For example, I could see myself writing:

> That's one of the do's on my *do's-and-don'ts* list

That might be justifiable, because the word *dos* looks more like the Spanish word for *two* than the plural of the word *do* (which is a word that isn't pluralized very often). However, I'd be willing to let a professional editor override that style choice.

I found one other [grammarbook website](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp) that talked about some of these very same issues, under Rule 2b, *Do not use an apostrophe + s to make a regular noun plural*:

> In special cases, such as when forming a plural of a word that is not normally a noun, some writers add an apostrophe for clarity.
>
> **Example**: Here are some do's and don'ts.
>
> In that sentence, the verb do is used as a plural noun, and the apostrophe was added because the writer felt that dos was confusing. Not all writers agree; some see no problem with dos and don'ts.
>
> However, with single lowercase letters, it is advisable to use apostrophes.
>
> **Example**: My a's look like u's.

The website goes on to say, "Imagine the confusion if you wrote that sentence without apostrophes. Readers would see *My as look like us,* and feel lost."

Comment: I really like this answer. Very well said, J.R. I've upvoted it!